# Unity xcode build failed - Framework Not found

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have unity game of my client, with AdMob and unityads in it.
While trying to create iPA, build failed with message.

I have already added UnityAds framework.

> "Ld /Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame normal armv7 (in target: Unity-iPhone)
>       cd /Volumes/MyData/Work/Fiver/MyGame/iOS\ Build/IOS
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.2.sdk -L/Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Volumes/MyData/Work/Fiver/MyGame/iOS\ Build/IOS/Libraries -L/Volumes/MyData/Work/Fiver/MyGame/iOS\ Build/IOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS -F/Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Volumes/MyData/Work/Fiver/MyGame/iOS\ Build/IOS/Frameworks -filelist /Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/MyGame-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame_lto.o -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/MyGame.app/MyGame -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -ObjC -framework UnityAds -framework WebKit -lCHAMoatMobileAppKit -liPhone-lib -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework Security -framework MediaToolbox -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework AVKit -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lil2cpp -framework AdColony -lChartboost -framework StoreKit -framework AdSupport -framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework Metal -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/shweta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dkrxbqnsqztdhcdgpfzagzqotqad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyGame

.

> ld: framework not found UnityAds
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)